# Best Practice for handling related entities in Application Service / (Microservice)

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, microservices, aspnetboilerplate

I have gone through few posts like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140193/best-approach-for-shared-entities-tables-among-multiple-applications) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653370/should-i-be-calling-an-appservice-from-another-appservice), etc. but I couldn't clarify a confusion with respect to design that's in my mind. What would be the best practice to add CRUD for related entities when working with `micro services`? *(my question is generally related to microservices, but currently I'm using [aspboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/), to be specific)*

For instance, I have an entity `Product` having around seven to ten properties in it. And then we may have another entity `ProductContract`. Each product can have multiple contracts added/updated.

**Question**: is it a good idea to create a separate Application Service for `ProductContract` entity? as it is going to have it's own input/output Dtos and logic, etc.

OR

It is better to create a `ProductContractManager` and keep its logic there. Then inject this manager into `Product` Application Service? This way, Product Application Service would have methods like 'AddProductContract', 'UpdateProductContract', etc.

Answer (score 1):

The main driver of whether `ProductContract` should be owned by a different service is the consistency requirements, because achieving stronger levels of consistency between microservices is difficult (especially without tying the services together at the DB level: if going down that way, the decision to have separate microservices should probably also be revisited).  So the main question you want to ask is, if updating/deleting a `Product` can there be a window of time where that update/delete isn't reflected in `ProductContract` (and vice versa)?

If the answer to that is that it can't, then you'll save yourself a lot of trouble by just putting responsibility for `ProductContract` in the same service that has responsibility for `Product`.  If eventual consistency is allowed, then a separate service might be called for: the consideration there isn't really technical but more related to human organization (who will be developing and maintaining the functionality) and expectations around whether `ProductContract` and `Product` will evolve together (functionality changes in one being likely to also lead to functionality changes in the other).

Comment: This answer helped me to understand one thing but rasied a question, reasonable scenario which I faced ATM is that what if update product not require update Contract but delete for sure yes. Is delete call from one micoservice to another BREAK the microservice architecture?